# THREEJS PointsMaterial texture transparency not work

Tags: three.js, shader, render, point, materials

Hello StackOverflow community
I have THREE Points Object and trying to create PointsMaterial but i cannot use transparent option

**1. Before adding transparent option**

```
new THREE.PointsMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff,
            map: pointTexture,
            size: 5,
            vertexColors: true,
            sizeAttenuation: false,
            depthWrite: true,
            depthTest: true,
            transparent: false,
            opacity: 0.5,
          });
```

[image]

**2. After adding transparent option**

```
new THREE.PointsMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff,
            map: pointTexture,
            size: 5,
            vertexColors: true,
            sizeAttenuation: false,
            depthWrite: true,
            depthTest: true,
            transparent: true,
            opacity: 0.5,
          });
```

[image]

Also if you have solution to blend point like this(maybe with shadermaterial) I gonna be very happy
[image]

ps: sorry for bad english or if post in not correctly write <3

Comment: You need to provide an [alpha map](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=points#api/en/materials/PointsMaterial.alphaMap).